# Is the str::random() function in Laravel reliable for short URL?

Tags: php, laravel, random, laravel-8, short-url

I'm trying to create a simple url shortener in my Laravel project. I want to use only lowercase and uppercase letters and numbers as short url addresses. (For example: sD7hY6g)
Is there a possibility that "Str::random()" function under "Illuminate\Support\Str" class in Laravel returns anything other than these characters? Can I trust this function or do I need to create my own custom function?

(In addition, whichever function I use, I check whether the code is already in the database before recording.)

Thank you to everyone who answered in advance.

Comment: `Str::random` will not guaranteee *uniqueness*. Better to use a different technique.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
In fact, there seems to be no function that promises uniqueness. Because according to my research, I have to manually check whether that code is already in the database before each record. What I want to learn here is whether this function will only return characters accepted for the URL. In other words, I want to find out if there is a possibility of anything other than small capital letters and numbers.

Comment: `Str::random()` uses PHP's [random_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) function. I personally create my own function, its easy to manage, better than `Str::random()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should you trust `Str::random()` to always return an alpha-numeric string? Yes.

The function normalizes its output by encoding to `base 64` number. The 64 symbols that represent a base 64 number are `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYVabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+\` and `=` for padding.

The function also replaces `\+=` to empty (white spaces), meaning that the only possible output for `Str::random()` are amongst `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYVabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789`.

---

Laravel 5+'s `Illuminate\Support\Str@random`

```php
public static function random($length = 16)
{
    $string = '';

    while (($len = strlen($string)) < $length) {
        $size = $length - $len;
        
        $bytes = random_bytes($size);
        
        $string .= substr(str_replace(['/', '+', '='], '', base64_encode($bytes)), 0, $size);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Why not using `bin2hex` directly as in `bin2hex(random_bytes($length))`?

Comment: Yes I am also interested in why bin2hex was not used, would it have increased the chance of collisions and reduced 'randomness' ?